# Parsing second level JSON objects in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Trying to simply print the second level of a JSON object

```
url = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    with url as result:
        # Check web response
        if result.status_code == 200:
            data = result.json()
            for obj in data['data']['attributes']:
                print(obj)
```

This prints all the values under attributes..there is about a dozen.  How can I print the values of each of those keys without explicitly naming them?

Comment: `data['data']['attributes']` is a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it is a dictionary.